# Passing data from AJAX call to view in React Native

Tags: ajax, react-native

I'm new to React, but know a lot about native iOS development.  I'm trying to wrap my head around the technology; I apologize in advance for my ignorance.  Please try to be helpful and not hurtful.  So I have a login page that works and passes data to the next view.  Code is here:

```
  _getHours = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    fetch('https://seniordevops.com/clockin/list', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        credentials: 'include'
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({ 
          isLoading: false , 
        });
        this.props.navigator.push({
          title: 'Clock In',
          component: Clockin,
          passProps: {intervals: responseJson}
        });
      })
      .catch(error =>
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          message: 'Something bad happened ' + error
      }));
  }
```

The next view is running smoothly and then I get to the part where I have to update the FlatList based on a similar API call, except with a parameter this time, code follows:

```
  _getHours = (currentProject) => {
    this.setState({currentProject: currentProject });
    fetch('https://seniordevops.com/clockin/list?project=' + currentProject, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      credentials: 'include',
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
    })
    .catch(error =>
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        message: 'Something bad happened ' + error
    }));
  }
```

Only this time, I'm not sure how to proceed.  My alert is giving back the JSON I want, I just don't know what to do with it.  Here' my FlatList:

```
<FlatList
  data={this.props.intervals}
  keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
  renderItem={this._renderItem}
  ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
/>
```

I know state is more for dynamic variables, but I passed in a prop originally.  Maybe I need to set a default prop and then pass state, idk.  How do I tell the FlatList I have new data and to re-render?  Aside/bonus question:  Should I consider refactoring to a network class at some point, and if so, use Redux?  Is that what that's for?  Concentrate on my main question and then bonus points if you could give me an overall networking strategy.

Comment: calling `setState` is what triggers rerenders. is `props.intervals` the data you want to change?

Comment: I figured it out, I chained together the data so that I set the state variable in componentDidMount()

Comment: Thanks for contributing.  When I did what I'd call a "segue" in iOS between ViewControllers, I passed in JSON via a prop, that's the props.intervals.  I just couldn't figure out the next step because I really needed the component to have a state.  The key was learning about componentDidMount in the React docs; that's what solved my knowledge gap.  Any tips on when to use Redux?

Answer (score 0):

Read docs, thought about it some more, here is my solution. Added this function to what the iOS equivalent is of a ViewController, in React we say default component class (I think?):

```
 componentDidMount() {
   this.setState({ hours: this.props.intervals});
 }
```

This function to me seems like the iOS version of ViewDidLoad().  It's where you're supposed to make API calls, but mine was already made from the previous ViewController, so I set the props that I passed it as an initial value.  Then changed my component to monitor the state instead of the prop.

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.hours}
  keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
  renderItem={this._renderItem}
  ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
/>
```

And of course, replaced the alert with a setState for the AJAX response.

```
.then((responseJson) => {
  this.setState({ hours: responseJson});
})
```